# Multiple Images selection from gallery in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Native Gallery for Android & iOS by yasirkula , an asset which can be used to select multiple images from gallery at once **following is an example code of single image selection Can someone please help that how to get multiple images selected at once.**

```
private void PickImage( int maxSize )
{
    NativeGallery.Permission permission = NativeGallery.GetImageFromGallery( ( path ) =>
    {
        Debug.Log( "Image path: " + path );
        if( path != null )
        {
            // Create Texture from selected image
            Texture2D texture = NativeGallery.LoadImageAtPath( path, maxSize );
            if( texture == null )
            {
                Debug.Log( "Couldn't load texture from " + path );
                return;
            }

            // Assign texture to a temporary quad and destroy it after 5 seconds
            GameObject quad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive( PrimitiveType.Quad );
            quad.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * 2.5f;
            quad.transform.forward = Camera.main.transform.forward;
            quad.transform.localScale = new Vector3( 1f, texture.height / (float) texture.width, 1f );

            Material material = quad.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
            if( !material.shader.isSupported ) // happens when Standard shader is not included in the build
                material.shader = Shader.Find( "Legacy Shaders/Diffuse" );

            material.mainTexture = texture;

            Destroy( quad, 5f );

            // If a procedural texture is not destroyed manually, 
            // it will only be freed after a scene change
            Destroy( texture, 5f );
        }
    }, "Select a PNG image", "image/png" );

    Debug.Log( "Permission result: " + permission );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There already exist a method for that: [`NativeGallery.GetImagesFromGallery`](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeGallery/blob/0bc6c23925e899e44506f13061287b0f24735957/Plugins/NativeGallery/NativeGallery.cs#L341) so (assuming the rest of your code works as expected) simply use that instead and iterate over the results like

```
NativeGallery.Permission permission = NativeGallery.GetImagesFromGallery((paths) =>
{
    foreach(var path in paths)
    {
        Debug.Log("Image path: " + path);
        if(path != null)
        {
            // Create Texture from selected image
            Texture2D texture = NativeGallery.LoadImageAtPath(path, maxSize);
            ....
        }
    }
}, "Select PNG images", "image/png");
```